# Dapp with Authentication System

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, mastering-ethereum

I know this question has been already asked many times, but I haven't got any satisfiable answer and so asking here.

I want to create an Authentication system dApp using reactjs. The user is having geth accounts and keyphrase with him. Now, using his account address and keyphrase, I want him to login to my dApp dashboard, do some stuff and then logout.

I need a proper guidance or some references to the tutorials about how to proceed with this.

What I found till now is:

1. using `web3.eth.accounts.sign(address, private_key)` during Login. And, it requires private_key, I want to know how to retrieve it from geth keystore.
2. calling `personal.unlockAccount(address, keyphrase)` during Login and then calling `personal.lockAccount()` during Logout.

Which approach to use?

Any suggestions/references would be appreciated!